# Method to create shortcode to add html opening and closing tags to string with php

Tags: php

I'm not sure if I am phrasing this right as it's not exactly shortcodes.

What I am trying to achieve is to create a function that find a replaces asterisks in my strings. But I need to alternate first and second replace.

```
$srting = 'Create personalised *tasty treats*';
```

I need to account for multiple uses of it, for example like this string below...

```
$srting = 'Create personalised *tasty treats* and branded *promotional products*';
```

The first `*` will be replaced with a opening `<span class="d-inline-block">`

The second `*` will be replaced with a closing `</span>`

And the the cycle repeats again for any more uses of `*` in the string.

I'm not sure what the most efficient way is to approach this, is this something that could be done with regex? Any ideas would be great thanks.

---

Updated working function below using accepted answer.

```
public static function word_break_fix($string) {

   $newString = preg_replace('/\\*([^*]*)\\*/s', '<span class="d-inline-block">\\1</span>', $string);

   return $newString;

}
```

Comment: Is this all you want? Or do you try to implement a complete *markdown* parser like on StackOverflow posts and comments?

Comment: This is just for some of my titles on my wordpress site, need to try and stop certain word combinations from being broken onto two lines.

Comment: You could use regex, something like `preg_replace('/\\*([^*]*)\\*/gs', '<tag>\\1</tag>', $subject)`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/i7fm8X/1 In PHP you should escape backslashes (double) since building from string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `preg_replace` capturing everything between two asterisks. You can reference a capturing group from the replacement by a backslashed number.

```
preg_replace('/\\*([^*]*)\\*/s', '<span class="d-inline-block">\\1</span>', $subject)
```

https://regex101.com/r/i7fm8X/1/

Note that in PHP regular expressions are built by strings, thus you escape characters once for the regex and the backslash is escaped again when using string literals.

Comment: Literally just built a function using this from your earlier comment. This worked perfectly, I was so surprised. Regex magic! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is absolutely something ideally suited for regex!

For tag replacement, something like this works well:

```
<?php

$string = 'Create personalised *tasty treats* and branded *promotional products* *tasty treats*';

$replace = preg_replace_callback("/(\\*[a-zA-Z\\s]*\\*)/m", function ($matches) {
    switch($matches[0])
    {
        case "*tasty treats*":
            return "Chocolate!";
        case "*promotional products*":
            return "DRINK COCA COLA!";
    }
    return $matches[0];
}, $string);

echo $replace;
```

Here's a link to Regex101 so you can see and learn how the regex works: https://regex101.com/r/pyCTZU/1

But to inject HTML as you specified, try this:

```
<?php

$string = 'Create personalised *tasty treats* and branded *promotional products* *tasty treats*';

$replace = preg_replace_callback("/(\\*[a-zA-Z\\s]*\\*)/m", function ($matches) {

    return "<span class=\"d-inline-block\">".substr($matches[0], 1, strlen($matches[0]) - 2)."</span>";

}, $string);

echo $replace;
```